# Jenkins ansible plugin can't find executable

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I'm running a Jenkins on Amazon EC2--the master in a Docker container and an agent on a separate box. My playbook executes an Ansible script, using the Jenkins Ansible plugin.

I had to install a new version of Ansible on the agent. I installed Ansible from git using the [Running from Source](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#running-from-source) instructions, and installed to `/home/ec2-user/ansible.` If I ssh to the agent and run `which ansible` I get `~/ansible/bin/ansible` as expected. I entered `/home/ec2-user/ansible/bin` in the 'Ansible executables directory' for my new install, at the Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration page.

When I run my Jenkins pipeline, however, I get this:

```
Running on docker-agent-1 in /home/ec2-user/jenkins/workspace/planet-healthcare-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] pwd
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Download source and capture commit ID)
[Pipeline] sh
[planet-healthcare-pipeline] Running shell script
+ which ansible
which: no ansible in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin)
```

It says it's running on `docker-agent-1` (which is the name of my agent), and I can see Ansible if I ssh there. Why can't Jenkins find the ansible executable?

**UPDATE:** After adding PATH as an environment variable, it can find Ansible, but now something else breaks. Here's the new output:

```
Running on docker-agent-1 in /home/ec2-user/jenkins/workspace/planet-healthcare-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] pwd
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Download source and capture commit ID)
[Pipeline] sh
[planet-healthcare-pipeline] Running shell script
+ which ansible
/home/ec2-user/ansible/bin/ansible
[Pipeline] sh
[planet-healthcare-pipeline] Running shell script
+ ansible --version
ansible 2.2.0 (devel 1975a545bd) last updated 2016/09/20 16:19:06 (GMT +000)
  lib/ansible/modules/core: (detached HEAD 70d4ff8e38) last updated 2016/09/20 16:19:08 (GMT +000)
  lib/ansible/modules/extras: (detached HEAD db7a3f48e1) last updated 2016/09/20 16:19:09 (GMT +000)
  config file = /home/ec2-user/jenkins/workspace/planet-healthcare-pipeline/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
[Pipeline] git
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:planetgroup/planethealthcareportal.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:planetgroup/planethealthcareportal.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Deployment key for Planet Healthcare Portal
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:planetgroup/planethealthcareportal.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision e69608a15c9d433e2a22824c7e607048332a4160 (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f e69608a15c9d433e2a22824c7e607048332a4160
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D develop # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b develop e69608a15c9d433e2a22824c7e607048332a4160
 > git rev-list e69608a15c9d433e2a22824c7e607048332a4160 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] sh
[planet-healthcare-pipeline] Running shell script
+ git rev-parse --verify HEAD
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] echo
Current commit ID: e69608a
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Copy application.yml to environment)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[planet-healthcare-pipeline] Running shell script
+ sudo cp **** config/application.yml
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build image)
[Pipeline] sh
[planet-healthcare-pipeline] Running shell script
+ docker build -t planethealthcare/portal_app .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 557.1 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.114 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.671 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.228 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.785 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.342 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.398 MB

Step 1 : FROM ruby:2.3
 ---> 7b66156f376c
Step 2 : MAINTAINER David Ham <dham@uxfactory.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 47f6f577f049
Step 3 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     build-essential     curl     gstreamer1.0-plugins-base     gstreamer1.0-tools     gstreamer1.0-x     libqt5webkit5-dev     qt5-default     xvfb     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*     && mkdir -p /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 38c1313e574d
Step 4 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 75a023d99fce
Step 5 : COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c39c81496a6b
Step 6 : ENV QMAKE /usr/bin/qmake
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3226bf5f4e63
Step 7 : RUN bundle install --retry 20
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 91cb9908d53a
Step 8 : COPY . ./
 ---> 7330a8f5ba7c
Removing intermediate container bd55b7deddaf
Step 9 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in 76e6418e2b3f
 ---> 81427ffb31f5
Removing intermediate container 76e6418e2b3f
Step 10 : CMD bundle exec rails server
 ---> Running in c2a90c3c59f6
 ---> 15ab02b3ab8d
Removing intermediate container c2a90c3c59f6
Successfully built 15ab02b3ab8d
[Pipeline] dockerFingerprintFrom
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run test suite)
[Pipeline] sh
[planet-healthcare-pipeline] Running shell script
+ docker run -d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=phc_portal_test postgres:9.5
[Pipeline] dockerFingerprintRun
[Pipeline] sh
[planet-healthcare-pipeline] Running shell script
+ docker inspect -f . planethealthcare/portal_app
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
$ docker run -t -d -u 500:500 --link 85511ce90ce11c24818ae63bbbf7ab47745be7d96807d450b4adebd4c3196c5e:postgres -p 3000:3000 -e RAILS_ENV=test -w /home/ec2-user/jenkins/workspace/planet-healthcare-pipeline -v /home/ec2-user/jenkins/workspace/planet-healthcare-pipeline:/home/ec2-user/jenkins/workspace/planet-healthcare-pipeline:rw -v /home/ec2-user/jenkins/workspace/planet-healthcare-pipeline@tmp:/home/ec2-user/jenkins/workspace/planet-healthcare-pipeline@tmp:rw -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** --entrypoint cat planethealthcare/portal_app
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
running tests...
[Pipeline] sh
[planet-healthcare-pipeline] Running shell script
+ rails db:migrate
/home/ec2-user/jenkins/workspace/planet-healthcare-pipeline@tmp/durable-32785ba4/script.sh: 2: /home/ec2-user/jenkins/workspace/planet-healthcare-pipeline@tmp/durable-32785ba4/script.sh: rails: not found
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop 3acf37726ce1061d2e0f6e8d0cec882c707b42e710916636b17aaece4f516f2d
$ docker rm -f 3acf37726ce1061d2e0f6e8d0cec882c707b42e710916636b17aaece4f516f2d
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] sh
[planet-healthcare-pipeline] Running shell script
+ docker stop 85511ce90ce11c24818ae63bbbf7ab47745be7d96807d450b4adebd4c3196c5e
85511ce90ce11c24818ae63bbbf7ab47745be7d96807d450b4adebd4c3196c5e
+ docker rm -f 85511ce90ce11c24818ae63bbbf7ab47745be7d96807d450b4adebd4c3196c5e
85511ce90ce11c24818ae63bbbf7ab47745be7d96807d450b4adebd4c3196c5e
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] mail
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

And here's the pipeline:

```
node('docker') {
    currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"

    try{
        def git_commit = ""
        def workspace = pwd()
        def APPLICATION_YML
        def image

        stage("Download source and capture commit ID") {
            sh "which ansible"
            sh "ansible --version"


            // Download source
            git branch: 'develop', credentialsId: 'b96345a1-543c-4ccd-9a86-deca7203625c', url: 'git@bitbucket.org:planetgroup/planethealthcareportal.git'

            // Get the commit ID
            sh 'git rev-parse --verify HEAD > GIT_COMMIT'
            git_commit = readFile('GIT_COMMIT').take(7)
            echo "Current commit ID: ${git_commit}"
        }

        stage("Copy application.yml to environment"){
            // write the application.yml to a file
            withCredentials([[$class: 'FileBinding', credentialsId: '67dbd2e7-008f-4463-89a6-9645060e8ec8', variable: 'APPLICATION_YML']]) {
                sh "sudo cp ${env.APPLICATION_YML} config/application.yml"
            }
        }

        stage("Build image"){
            image = docker.build "planethealthcare/portal_app"
        }

        stage("Run test suite"){
            // start postgres
            def postgres95 = docker.image('postgres:9.5')
            postgres95.withRun("-p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=phc_portal_test"){ postgres ->
                image.inside("--link ${postgres.id}:postgres -p 3000:3000 -e RAILS_ENV=test") {
                    echo "running tests..."
                    sh "rails db:migrate"
                    sh "rspec --tag ~pending"
                    sh "cucumber"
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Push to ECR registry"){
            docker.withRegistry('https://0000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 'ecr:dham'){
                image.push "${git_commit}"
                image.push 'latest'
            }
        }

        stage("Deploy app"){
            // run the playbook
            ansiblePlaybook([
              colorized: true,
              credentialsId: 'planet-healthcare',
              installation: 'ansible-2-2-0',
              inventory: 'staging',
              playbook: 'deploy.yml',
              extras: "--extra-vars 'app_build_id=${git_commit}''"
            ])
        }
    }

    catch(err) {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"

        mail body: "project build error: ${err}\n\n\n ${currentBuild.description}" ,
        subject: 'project build failed',
        to: 'me@example.com'

        throw err
    }

}
```

It's failing in the "Run test suite" stage--it can't find `rails` to run `rails db:migrate`, even though I know it's in the container.

Why would setting PATH on the agent affect a script that happens inside a Docker container?

Answer (score 1):

Do you execute `which ansible` in your script? It searches only defined PATHs.
And it seems `/home/ec2-user/ansible/bin` is not in `/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin` (from  your output).
You may go to agent-node's settings in Jenkins and add `PATH` environment variable with `$PATH:/home/ec2-user/ansible/bin` value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did what you said, and that worked, but now commands in the Docker container break. Updated answer above.